# getting a  ? and a [✘?] instead of just the branch icon and the branch name on zsh

Tags: bash, git, zsh, command-prompt, ps1

I was just trying to learn git, and the guy on the tutorial talked about zsh, so I followed a tutorial to install it and I am getting a  ?[✘?] instead of the branch name on `zsh` shell.
what should I do?
[image]

Comment: what's the value of your `echo $PS1` For ex: mine show: `%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt) `

Comment: @AKS $(spaceship_prompt)

Comment: what that writer meant was, you have to grab the some funny ascii code for a SPACE SHIP emoji and put it within the brackets. There are other links too, the one you are using seems old. https://dev.to/thatjoemoore/emojifying-my-bash-prompt or https://medium.com/@joshuaxavier/how-to-customise-your-command-prompt-to-include-an-emoji-647e1f3e4027

Comment: The funky characters that look like a branch are not entirely standard. See, e.g., http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2016/03/sbt-customize-shell-prompt-with-git.html

Comment: It seems the font you're using to render those glyphs does not have some of the required unicodes.

Answer (score 0):

Those icons next to the branch are [git status indicators](https://spaceship-prompt.sh/options/#git-status-git_status). The ✘ means there are deleted files and ? means there are untracked changes.